# select option html

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-select

Подскажите, можно ли как то сделать, что бы при выборе значения из списка вида `select option` выпадающий `option` был заданной ширины и текст в нем был не одной строкой на весь экран, а переносился в пределах той ширины, которая задана этому option?

Есть задача сделать выпадающий список в пределах одной ячейки и что бы содержимое `optionов` не выходило за рамки установленные параметром `width` но было видно полностью, а не скрывалось за границей.

Comment: вы хоть бы скриншот приложили бы или пример где Вы такое видели

Comment: Тяжело помогать, когда непонятно что именно надо…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать с помощью нескольких radio, нескольких label и одного div.

Корневая label будет всегда видимой частью нашего альтернативного select. При клике на нее будет переключаться основной radio, который и отвечает за состояния открыт/закрыт у этой конструкции. Placeholder и традиционная стрелочка будут реализованы через псевдоэлементы :before и :after у корневой label. Все остальное, кроме wrapper (тот самый единственный div), по умолчанию скрыто. Почему мы не скрываем wrapper? Потому что в нем находится выбранный элемент (если такой есть), а он должен быть виден всегда.

```css
label.selectGeneral {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}


/** Это обещанный placeholder **/

label.selectGeneral:before {
  content: attr(placeholder);
  /** Взять текст из атрибута placeholder **/
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  max-width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
  /** Не переносить слова **/
  color: #adadad;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  /** Скрыть лишнее **/
}


/** А это стрелочка **/

label.selectGeneral:after {
  content: "<>";
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

label.selectGeneral input,
label.selectGeneral label {
  display: none;
}

label.selectGeneral div {
  min-width: 100%;
  max-height: 500px;
  /** Ограничения на высоту списка выборов **/
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!-- Это wrapper для вариантов выбора -->
<div>
  <!-- Группа radio и есть аналог оригинальных option -->
  <input type="radio" name="OS" value="linux" id="OS[linux]">
  <!-- Аналог видимой части option -->
  <label for="OS[linux]">linux</label>

  <input type="radio" name="OS" value="windows" id="OS[windows]">
  <label for="OS[windows]">windows</label>

  <input type="radio" name="OS" value="other" id="OS[other]">
  <label for="OS[other]">other</label>
</div>
</label>
```

Соответственно после, можно уже оперировать стилями и подстраивать под свой проект

Источник:
https://habr.com/post/248243/

Comment: Да. Такой вариант я сделал через 30 минут после того, как задал тут вопрос) Это полу мера конечно, но на первое время сойдет. Недостататок использования стилизованных radio в том, что по клику они не исчезают а текст из них не вставляется в нужное поле. Доработал на Js и вставляется и норм все, но блин. Куча стилей+js вместо обычного селекта... Надеюсь когда нибудь они добавят такую "примочку", что бы селект и option мог принимать параметры height/width и word-wrap как обычный div . Konstantin Fedorov лайк просто за поиски в гугле)

Comment: В варианте, который я нашел - по клику закрывается блок с опциями, попробуй

Comment: Обязательно гляну.